# Can GPS give locations along with timings in android?

Tags: android, gps

I am working on 1 application where we need to store location of user based on GPS. At the same time we need time also.

as per wikipedia, GPS can give UTC time also, but i don't find specific android api using which we can work out.

Please let me know which android location api/sample code can help me to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I think the GeoLocation API is what you are looking for.
Refer to this for more details: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/location/index.html

It will provide a Location object on updates which can return the UTC time through the getTime() method.

And refer to this to get the address refering to the location:
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/location/display-address.html